# What do the python file extensions, .pyc .pyd .pyo stand for?

Tags: python, pyc

What do these python file extensions mean?

- `.pyc`
- `.pyd`
- `.pyo`

What are the differences between them and how are they generated from a *.py file?

Answer (score 557, accepted):

1. `.py`: This is normally the input source code that you've written.
2. `.pyc`: This is the compiled bytecode. If you import a module, python will build a `*.pyc` file that contains the bytecode to make importing it again later easier (and faster).
3. `.pyo`:  This was a file format used before Python 3.5 for `*.pyc` files that were created with optimizations (`-O`) flag. (see the note below)
4. `.pyd`: This is basically a windows dll file. http://docs.python.org/faq/windows.html#is-a-pyd-file-the-same-as-a-dll

Also for some further discussion on `.pyc` vs `.pyo`, take a look at: [http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/pytut/CompiledPythonfiles.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20160130165632/http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/pytut/CompiledPythonfiles.html) (I've copied the important part below)

> - When the Python interpreter is invoked with the -O flag, optimized code is generated and stored in ‘.pyo’ files. The optimizer currently doesn't help much; it only removes assert statements. When -O is used, all bytecode is optimized; .pyc files are ignored and .py files are compiled to optimized bytecode.
> - Passing two -O flags to the Python interpreter (-OO) will cause the bytecode compiler to perform optimizations that could in some rare cases result in malfunctioning programs. Currently only `__doc__` strings are removed from the bytecode, resulting in more compact ‘.pyo’ files. Since some programs may rely on having these available, you should only use this option if you know what you're doing.
> - A program doesn't run any faster when it is read from a ‘.pyc’ or ‘.pyo’ file than when it is read from a ‘.py’ file; the only thing that's faster about ‘.pyc’ or ‘.pyo’ files is the speed with which they are loaded.
> - When a script is run by giving its name on the command line, the bytecode for the script is never written to a ‘.pyc’ or ‘.pyo’ file. Thus, the startup time of a script may be reduced by moving most of its code to a module and having a small bootstrap script that imports that module. It is also possible to name a ‘.pyc’ or ‘.pyo’ file directly on the command line.

**Note:**

On 2015-09-15 the [Python 3.5 release](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-488-elimination-of-pyo-files) implemented PEP-488 and eliminated `.pyo` files. 
This means that `.pyc` files represent both unoptimized and optimized bytecode.

Comment: Are the dll files generated from python scripts or c/c++ scripts?

Comment: @yankitwizzy: Yeah. They should be generated from C/C++ code. The file should be in machine code, so it can't be directly from python.

Comment: "The optimizer currently doesn't help much; it only removes assert statements.". Are you sure about this? Try ```def f(x):
    assert(x**5 == x*x*x*x*x);
    return x;

import timeit;
print(timeit.repeat("for x in range(100): f(x)", "from __main__ import f",
                           number=10000));```

Comment: @J.C.Leitão: Am I sure about what? Could you explain what you think your example shows rather than just throwing code in a comment.

Comment: @BillLynch: packages typically have asserts, and removing asserts do help speeding it up (the code on the comment was just a simple example of it). Saying that "it doesn't help much" seems to me too harsh given the consequences of removing asserts from imported code, specially from well maintained packages that use asserts. I'm sorry for the previous low-quality comment.

Comment: Note that [in Python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.5.html), [PEP 488](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0488/) is implemented, which does away with the concept of `.pyo` files.  Even optimized bytecode ends with the `.pyc` extension Python 3.5, then.

Comment: @BillLynch Any idea what is `.py{}` extension?

Answer (score 276):

- **.py** - Regular script
- **.py3** - (rarely used) Python3 script. Python3 scripts usually end with ".py" not ".py3", but I have seen that a few times
- **.pyc** - compiled script (Bytecode)
- **.pyo** - optimized pyc file (As of Python3.5, Python will only use pyc rather than pyo and pyc)
- **.pyw** - Python script to run in Windowed mode, without a console; executed with pythonw.exe
- **.pyx** - Cython src to be converted to C/C++
- **.pyd** - Python script made as a Windows DLL
- **.pxd** - Cython modern header for use with `cimport`s.
- **.pxi** - Cython legacy header for raw text `include`s.
- **.pyi** - Stub file ([PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#stub-files))
- **.pyz** - Python script archive ([PEP 441](https://peps.python.org/pep-0441/)); this is a script containing compressed Python scripts (ZIP) in binary form after the standard Python script header
- **.pyzw** - Python script archive for MS-Windows ([PEP 441](https://peps.python.org/pep-0441/)); this is a script containing compressed Python scripts (ZIP) in binary form after the standard Python script header
- **.py[cod]** - wildcard notation in ".gitignore" that means the file may be ".pyc", ".pyo", or ".pyd".
- **.pth** - a path configuration file; its contents are additional items (one per line) to be added to `sys.path`. See [`site`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#module-site) module.
- **.egg** - special zip used for distribution/import, mostly obsolete since [PEP 427](https://peps.python.org/pep-0427/)
- **.whl** - special zip used for distribution only, widely used by `pip`

A larger list of additional Python file-extensions (mostly rare and unofficial) can be found at http://dcjtech.info/topic/python-file-extensions/

Comment: It should be noted that a «.pyx» file is not quite Python source which is converted to C, but rather Cython source code (i.e.: waiting to be converted to C)

Comment: What does "I" represent in PYI extension? "Include" / "Implementation" / "Interface"?

Comment: .pyw means PYthon script which creates a Window, not Python 4 Windows. .pyw can be executed under *nix

Comment: In general .pyw is a script to run in Windowed mode, i.e. without a console output. As @VladislavToncharov states they can be run on _most_ platforms that support python _if it is installed_.

Comment: This answer should discuss `.pth` files.

Answer (score 1):

`.py` : The input source code that you have written.

`.pyc` : The compiled bytecode. If you import a module, python  will build a `.pyc`
a file that contains the bytecode to make importing it again later easier(and
faster).

`.pyo` : A `.pyc` file that was created while optimizations (-O) were on.

`.pyd` : A windows DLL file for python.