# How do I install Python OpenCV through Conda?

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to install OpenCV for Python through [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)), but I can't seem to figure this out.

I tried

```
conda install opencv
conda install cv2
```

I also tried searching

```
conda search cv
```

No cigar. I ran across this which lists `opencv` as an included package:

http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkgs.html

After running `conda info` I noticed my version is 3.4.1, but I couldn't seem to find any information about this version online. I'm pretty confused about this.

Am I missing something pretty obvious here? If `opencv` was available for a previous version of Anaconda, then why wouldn't it be available for the newer version? And why does that link only show me documentation for version 1.9.2?

Comment: the current opencv wrapper module is called cv2. (the first one in you list is an outdated 3rd party wrapper, the 3rd one is the outdated c-api wrapper, you should use none of those) - unfortunately, i never met a person running it successfully on anaconda. can't you use a regular python 2.7 ?

Comment: There's nothing with anaconda that prevents you from using it with opencv. It's just not included in the conda install except for linux. You can get install binaries files from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) for windows.

Comment: ah, thanks, M4rtini, i was obviously wrong above.

Comment: I'm on MacOSX. Only available on linux? whats with that? how did you find that?

Comment: @Chet In the table you linked, there's an L behind the listing of opencv. If you look beneath the table you will se that that L means it's only for Linux.

Comment: It works already from the standard repo: ```conda install opencv```

Comment: I just installed OpenCV 3 on python 3.6.1 on a windows 10 machine using https://www.solarianprogrammer.com/2016/09/17/install-opencv-3-with-python-3-on-windows/

Comment: everybody. I found that using other owners of the Anaconda Cloud Repository works as well. e.g. instead of using menpo's opencv y used conda-forge's. here are the owners of several OpenCVs listed with the respective OSs: https://anaconda.org/search?q=openCV I ran this code:
conda install -c conda-forge opencv=3.2.0 Good luck!

Comment: why not just use pip install ?

Comment: @ng0323, take a look at this: https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/. It is not recommended to use both pip and conda because it can result in instability.

Comment: With anaconda 3, type `conda install opencv` command on annaconda prompt. Installs 3.4.1 opencv and various dependent packages with it. Worked for me and also it did not require any custom installing specification.

Comment: **NOTE:** There is likely a version of the package for your system available on the official Anaconda channel or the popular conda-forge. Check there before trying to install things from github or random channels, or using pip.

Comment: [OpenCV on Anaconda's website](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv).

Answer (score 272):

You can install it using binstar:

```
conda install -c menpo opencv
```

Comment: I tried using this method to install OpenCV, but am running into an issue where when I type import cv I get the error DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. I was wondering if you ran into this issue during your install.

Comment: Worked for me on windows 7

Comment: This was a bug in me copying the files, it should work now

Comment: Yes! Works for me on OSX, python 3.4. Installs opencv3.0 (presumably conda's default still has opencv 2.x which wasn't py3 compatible)

Comment: Hmmm, although this doesn't allow me to `import cv2.cv` (am I missing something obvious?)

Comment: @AndyHayden `cv2.cv` was [deprecated in OpenCV3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132081/is-cv2-cv-missing-in-opencv-3-0)

Comment: @BeRecursive Thanks! Do you know if there is a list/porting guide somewhere (for code that uses cv2.cv functions/constants) ? e.g. cv.X becomes cv2.Y?

Comment: This works on OSX 10.10.5 with conda 13.8.4 The only "minor" issue is that it requires numpy 1.10.1 which is ok but I ran conda update --all and some libraries required a downgrade to 1.9 in order to run.

Comment: I found that this worked for my when using PyCharm IDE, Anaconda 2.7 and Ubuntu 14.04 whereas "conda install opencv" did not. Thanks!

Comment: I'm finding that cv2.VideoCapture does not work. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, Anaconda 2.7 and PyCharm IDE. Is there a way to tell if this conda package is compiled with ffmpeg support? (I'm fairly new to both anaconda and Ubuntu)

Comment: This worked fine with Anaconda 2.7 on Win10 64bit, whereas `conda install opencv` did not.

Comment: This binstar package is not compiled with ffmpeg support. You can check with `print cv2.getBuildInformation().split("Video I/O:")[-1].split("\n\n")[0]`. I found that `msarahan` has 3.1 compiled with ffmpeg for OS X, but I still can't find one for linux; don't know about windows.

Comment: Be sure to type opencv rather than opencv3 at end of the command. It doesn't work for me with opencv3 and looks like it's because depended packages are not downgraded that caused conflicts.

Comment: NOTE: this repo has opencv 2.4.11 as of writing. For opencv 3.2 you'll need another method.

Comment: @drevicko what's the other method?

Comment: @MonaJalal to be honest I don't have one. There's quite a few install scripts out there for various setups, some of which may work. I didn't find a good solution, but didn't look especially hard. If you're super keen, you may want to update the menpo conda install script

Comment: Using this
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/mona/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libopenblasp-r0.2.19.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/mona/anaconda/lib/libopencv_core.3.3.dylib
  Reason: image not found

Comment: mportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: @mercergeoinfo is there any way this can be resolved?  I'm trying to use both `numpy` 1.15-exclusive functions (`np.unique(x,axis=0)`) and funcs from `import cv2` in my code.   I am willing to try a mix of conda and pip if necessary.  I'm guessing the issue is `cv2` uses old `numpy` functions which are deprecated?

Comment: UPDATE : opencv-python 3.4.0.12 has supported video related functions, so we can use pip install opencv-python as normal. . Just "pip install opencv-python" and it worked :)

Comment: **Outdated answer.** The `menpo` channel is no longer actively maintained. Please update answer.

Answer (score 155):

`conda install opencv` currently works for me on UNIX/python2. This is worth trying first before consulting other solutions.

Comment: It worked for me three, on Ubuntu 14.04.  :-)  THANKS!

Comment: Not with python 3.4: `Error: Unsatisfiable package specifications.`

Comment: Using just "conda install opencv" on Ubuntu 14.04 with Anaconda 2.7 and PyCharm throws an error when I use 'cv2.imshow('name',img) that indicates that the package needs to be rebuilt with "GTK+ 2.x" support, so does not appear to be useful for somebody using PyCharm as an IDE on ubuntu.

Comment: @PhilGlau I got the same error trying to install this way. It's a shame b/c it's so much easier installing with conda than manually (which I still haven't got working correctly).

Comment: It looks like it would work but it is trying to downgrade my numpy from 1.10 to 1.7 which is unacceptable.

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks alot @singular.

Comment: Does `conda search opencv` return results for you?  It didn't for me.

Comment: it really depends on platform. for example this doesn't work for windows. can do a `conda search --platform {win-32 / win-64 / osx-64 / etc...} opencv` to see what is available

Comment: Works under Ubuntu 16.04 with Python 3.6. Thanks.

Comment: Works with Ubuntu 18.04 and Python 3.6

Comment: Works on Windows 10, Python 3.7. You may need to run cmd with admin privileges.

Comment: Works on Mac OSX Mojave 10.14.5

Comment: Still works for me on OS X 16.01 and Python 3.9

Comment: It takes forever.... why should I wait so long for something I can do with just `pip install`?  I have not felt the advantage of using conda and already I'm in tears.

Answer (score 128):

This worked for me (on Ubuntu and conda 3.18.3):

```
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo opencv3
```

The command above was what was shown to me when I ran the following:

```
anaconda show menpo/opencv3
```

This was the output:

```
To install this package with conda run:
     conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo opencv3
```

I tested the following in python without errors:

```
>>> import cv2
>>>
```

Comment: Trying many other ways to install opencv3, this finally worked for me on OSX 10.10.5

Comment: Up you go sir! This worked for Ubuntu 14.04, Anaconda with Python 3.5

Comment: Worked for me too on Windows 10

Comment: Superb. Worked wonderfully well. tried many other options and thank fully I found this. Thank you so much. Windows 8.1 X64

Comment: interestingly this installs a cv2.pyd that is ~2.3 MB. But if you go to the openCV website and download the binary, the opencv2.pyd from there is >44MB. Furthermore , both pyd files pass the 'import' test. So I wonder why the anaconda repo is much smaller?

Comment: Sir, you saved me a day :) python3.5 ubuntu16.04 Working like a charm!

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me (python 3.5, win64)

Comment: ```---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c8ec22b3e787> in <module>()
----> 1 import cv2
ImportError: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: `apt-get install libgtk2.0-0` is required

Comment: You my friend are a genius!! This is like the only way and best way to install OpenCV! Thank you so much!

Comment: Worked like a charm! (Ubuntu16 LTS)

Comment: How comes you are installing `opencv3` but importing `cv2`? Why are the version numbers different?

Comment: won't work this python3.7, hence `pip install opencv-python`

Comment: **Outdated answer.** The `menpo` channel is no longer actively maintained. Please update answer.

Answer (score 85):

I have summarized my now fully working solution, *[OpenCV-Python - How to install OpenCV-Python package to Anaconda (Windows)](https://mathalope.co.uk/2015/05/07/opencv-python-how-to-install-opencv-python-package-to-anaconda-windows/)*. Nevertheless I've copied and pasted the important bits to this post.

---

At the time of writing I was using Windows 8.1, 64-bit machine, Anaconda/ Python 2.x. (see notes below - this works also for Windows 10, and likely Python 3.x too).

- NOTE 1: as mentioned mentioned by [@great_raisin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3177442/great-raisin) (thank you) in comment section however, this solution appears to also work for Windows 10.
- NOTE 2: this will probably work for Anaconda/Python 3.x too. If you are using Windows 10 and Anaconda/Python 3.x, and this solution works, please add a comment below. Thanks! (Update: noting from comment "Working on Windows 10")
- NOTE 3: depending on whether you are using Python 2.x or 3.x, just adjust the `print` statement accordingly in code snippets. i.e. in Python 3.x it would be `print("hello")`, and in Python 2.x it would be `print "hello"`.

## TL;DR

To use OpenCV fully with Anaconda (and Spyder IDE), we need to:

1. Download the OpenCV package from [the official OpenCV site](https://web.archive.org/web/20170304092804/http://opencv.org:80/downloads.html?)
2. Copy and paste the `cv2.pyd` to the Anaconda site-packages directory.
3. Set user environmental variables so that Anaconda knows where to find the FFMPEG utility.
4. Do some testing to confirm OpenCV and FFMPEG are now working.

(Read on for the detail instructions...)

## Prerequisite

### Install Anaconda

Anaconda is essentially a nicely packaged Python IDE that is shipped with tons of useful packages, such as NumPy, Pandas, IPython Notebook, etc. It seems to be recommended everywhere in the scientific community. Check out [Anaconda](https://web.archive.org/web/20170814033303/https://www.continuum.io/downloads) to get it installed.

### Install OpenCV-Python to Anaconda

Cautious Note: I originally tried out installing the binstar.org OpenCV package, as suggested. That method however does not include the FFMPEG codec - i.e. you may be able to use OpenCV, but you won't be able to process videos.

The following instruction works for me is inspired by this [OpenCV YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EcFtefHEEII). So far I have got it working on both my desktop and laptop, both 64-bit machines and Windows 8.1.

#### Download OpenCV Package

Firstly, go to the [official OpenCV site](https://opencv.org/releases/) to download the complete OpenCV package. Pick a version you like (2.x or 3.x). I am on Python 2.x and OpenCV 3.x - mainly because this is how the [OpenCV-Python Tutorials](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html) are setup/based on.

In my case, I've extracted the package (essentially a folder) straight to my C drive (`C:\opencv`).

#### Copy and Paste the cv2.pyd file

The Anaconda Site-packages directory (e.g. `C:\Users\Johnny\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages` in my case) contains the Python packages that you may import. Our goal is to copy and paste the `cv2.pyd` file to this directory (so that we can use the `import cv2` in our Python codes.).

To do this, copy the `cv2.pyd` file...

From this OpenCV directory (the beginning part might be slightly different on your machine). For Python 3.x, I guess, just change the `2.x` to `3.x` accordingly.

```
# Python 2.7 and 32-bit machine:
C:\opencv\build\python\2.7\x84

# Python 2.7 and 64-bit machine:
C:\opencv\build\python\2.7\x64
```

To this Anaconda directory (the beginning part might be slightly different on your machine):

```
C:\Users\Johnny\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages
```

After performing this step we shall now be able to use `import cv2` in Python code. BUT, we still need to do a little bit more work to get FFMPEG (video codec) to work (to enable us to do things like processing videos).

#### Set Environmental Variables

Right-click on "My Computer" (or "This PC" on Windows 8.1) → left-click *Properties* → left-click "Advanced" tab → left-click "Environment Variables..." button.

Add a new User Variable to point to the OpenCV (either x86 for 32-bit system or x64 for 64-bit system). I am currently on a 64-bit machine.

```
| 32-bit or 64 bit machine? | Variable     | Value                                |
|---------------------------|--------------|--------------------------------------|
| 32-bit                    | `OPENCV_DIR` | `C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12`           |
| 64-bit                    | `OPENCV_DIR` | `C:\opencv\build\x64\vc12`           |
```

Append `%OPENCV_DIR%\bin` to the User Variable `PATH`.

For example, my `PATH` user variable looks like this...

Before:

```
C:\Users\Johnny\Anaconda;C:\Users\Johnny\Anaconda\Scripts
```

After:

```
C:\Users\Johnny\Anaconda;C:\Users\Johnny\Anaconda\Scripts;%OPENCV_DIR%\bin
```

This is it we are done! FFMPEG is ready to be used!

### Test to confirm

We need to test whether we can now do these in Anaconda (via Spyder IDE):

- Import OpenCV package
- Use the FFMPEG utility (to read/write/process videos)

#### Test 1: Can we import OpenCV?

To confirm that Anaconda is now able to import the OpenCV-Python package (namely, `cv2`), issue these in the IPython console:

```
import cv2
print cv2.__version__
```

If the package `cv2` is imported OK with no errors, and the `cv2` version is printed out, then we are all good! Here is a snapshot:

[image: import-cv2-ok-in-anaconda-python-2.png]
<sub>(source: [mathalope.co.uk](http://mathalope.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/import-cv2-ok-in-anaconda-python-2.png))</sub>

#### Test 2: Can we Use the FFMPEG codec?

Place a sample `input_video.mp4` video file in a directory. We want to test whether we can:

- read this `.mp4` video file, and
- write out a new video file (can be `.avi` or `.mp4` etc.)

To do this we need to have a test Python code, call it `test.py`. Place it in the same directory as the sample `input_video.mp4` file.

This is what `test.py` may look like (I've listed out both newer and older version codes here - do let us know which one works / not work for you!).

(Newer version...)

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("input_video.mp4")
print cap.isOpened()   # True = read video successfully. False - fail to read video.

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter("output_video.avi", fourcc, 20.0, (640, 360))
print out.isOpened()  # True = write out video successfully. False - fail to write out video.

cap.release()
out.release()
```

(Or the older version...)

```
import cv2
cv2.VideoCapture("input_video.mp4")
print cv2.isOpened()   # True = read video successfully. False - fail to read video.

fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter("output_video.avi",fourcc, 20.0, (640,360))
print out.isOpened()  # True = write out video successfully. False - fail to write out video.

cap.release()
out.release()
```

This test is VERY IMPORTANT. If you'd like to process video files, you'd need to ensure that Anaconda / Spyder IDE can use the FFMPEG (video codec). It took me days to have got it working. But I hope it would take you much less time! :)

Note: One more very important tip when using the Anaconda Spyder IDE. Make sure you check the current working directory (CWD)!!!

## Conclusion

To use OpenCV fully with Anaconda (and Spyder IDE), we need to:

1. Download the OpenCV package from the [official OpenCV site](https://opencv.org/releases/)
2. Copy and paste the `cv2.pyd` to the Anaconda site-packages directory.
3. Set user environmental variables so that Anaconda knows where to find the FFMPEG utility.
4. Do some testing to confirm OpenCV and FFMPEG are now working.

Good luck!

Comment: Brilliant answer! Note that if you're using conda environments, `cv2.pyd` should be added to the environment's `site-packages` folder (e.g. `C:\Users\cod3monk3y\Anaconda\envs\foo\Lib\site-packages\cv2.pyd`). Also worth noting, the .pyd file is [just a Windows DLL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8822335/1174169) with a specific interface to play nicely with Python.

Comment: the code you posted above prints out true, true for me but the output is an empty 6kb video file. However, the code below writes properly to a file. (how do i get line breaks in these comments?)

Comment: `import cv2`

`cap = cv2.VideoCapture("BBunny_360x240_1mb.mp4")`
`print cap.isOpened() `
`fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')`
`out = cv2.VideoWriter("output_video.avi", fourcc, 30.0, (320, 240))`
`print out.isOpened() `

`while True:`
` ret, frame = cap.read()`
` out.write(frame)`
` cv2.imshow('frame',frame)`
` if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF ==ord('q'):`
`  break`

`cap.release()`
`out.release()`
`cv2.destroyAllWindows()`

Comment: the bunny video i used came from here [http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/240/big_buck_bunny_240p_1mb.mp4]

Comment: Thank you, your post helped me a lot. I am getting an error with cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc ('module' object has no attribute 'VideoWriter_fourcc'), however I successfully read from a file which is what I wanted for a start. Do you have any clue what might be causing the above error? Thanks again.

Comment: I get two times false. Don't know why. I did install FFmpeg and added it to the path. Using the "new version" code, but with the older line fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID') because print cv2.isOpened() generates an Attribute error: 'module'object has no attribute 'isOpened'. Also, the cap.release in the "old version" does not make sense as it is not defined. Win 7, 64 bit, Anaconda, VS15

Comment: If i could up it more i would, best answer ever. I would just add, if you've installed python, uninstall it, conda has its own

Comment: Thanks for this! One more suggested test that took me awhile to figure out. After confirming that the video can be opened, I wanted to confirm that I could extract a frame (frame 100) as an array. In openCV 2.4.9, the command for this was cap.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 100). In openCV 3.2.0, the equivalent command has changed to cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 100)

Comment: Thank you sir for this awesome and well explained answer. You are making the life easier for many newbies sir !

Comment: Working on Windows 10

Comment: This is how to install opencv WITHOUT using conda.  -1

Answer (score 33):

You can install OpenCV by running these commands in the Anaconda command prompt:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge

conda install libopencv opencv py-opencv
```

Source:

https://github.com/conda-forge/opencv-feedstock

Comment: (this is duplicate existing answer, w/ edits, not sure which came first) menpo repo no longer supported, https://github.com/menpo/conda-opencv3 ; now recommended to use conda-forge https://github.com/conda-forge/opencv-feedstock

Comment: If using miniconda under ubuntu 18.04; the "Solving environment" stage will take very long if you have the newest anaconda package installed. create a clean miniconda env without the anaconda bulk (e.g. `conda create --name abc python=2.7` )

Answer (score 31):

It doesn't seem like the page you linked includes `opencv` any more. (Funny, I do recall it being included at a previous point as well.)

In any case, installation of OpenCV into Anaconda, although unavailable through conda, is pretty trivial. You just need to download one file.

1. Download OpenCV from https://opencv.org/releases/ and extract
2. From the extracted folder, copy the file from the extracted directory: opencv/build/python/2.7/(either x86 or x64, depending on your Anaconda version)/cv2.pyd to your Anaconda site-packages directory, e.g., C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages
3. To get FFmpeg within `opencv` to work, you'll have to add the directory that FFmpeg is located in to the path (e.g., opencv/sources/3rdparty/ffmpeg). Then you'll have to find the DLL file in that folder (e.g., opencv_ffmpeg_64.dll) and *copy or rename it* to a filename that includes the `opencv` version you are installing, (e.g., opencv_ffmpeg249_64) for 2.4.9.

Now at the Python prompt you should be able to type "import cv2"...to verify that it works, type "print cv2.__version__", and it should print out the OpenCV version you downloaded.

Comment: Somebody also created a binstar package, which you should be able to download through Conda now: https://binstar.org/menpo/opencv/files

Comment: can you tell me how to download opencv via conda ? I downloaded the mac package in the above link what do I do from there?

Comment: @venuktan conda install opencv should do it.

Comment: @eculeus could you elaborate a little more on verifying ffmpeg.  I can read from my webcam but am having trouble reading/writing video files.  I looked in that directory 3rdparty/ffmpeg and renmaed dll to: opencv_ffmpeg300_64.dll   You mention that ffmpeg should be in path. Do you mean path of windows PATH or of sys.path in python?

Comment: Note that you may need to import sys, then do a sys.path.append("C:/Anaconda/Lib/site-packages").  The above had suddenly stopped working and this solution came from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876079/opencv-cannot-find-module-cv2

Comment: Can someone please elaborate the part for the ffmpeg DLL? I found it, but I have no clue what to rename it to, where to put it, and what's meant by "path". Is that `sys.path` or `PATH`?

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 25):

In May 2019, the answer is as follows for MacOS:

```
conda update freetype
conda install opencv -c conda-forge
```

This updates `libfreetype.6.dylib` to 24.0.0 compatibility and installs OpenCV 4.1.0.

Comment: will this install "cv2" ?

Comment: @AdamErickson was this in Anaconda Prompt run as Admin?

Comment: @mLstudent33 The command was run in Bash and the Anaconda installation was in a local folder, so no `sudo` was necessary. I would avoid running `conda` as `sudo` unless you manage a system-wide install for multiple users, which I also do. In that case, I am usually careful to activate the conda environment and then `sudo ./conda ...` from the `/bin` folder of that environment as an extra precaution, since `sudo` changes your `PATH` even when using the `-E` flag.

Comment: @AdamErickson this worked for me, but I got v3.4.2 instead. Any ideas?

Comment: update to above: I think I already had an earlier version of `libopencv` installed already. After removing it running `conda install opencv` installed the latest version.

Answer (score 21):

The following installs `opencv` from `conda-forge` (note: tried on Windows)

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install opencv
```

Comment: menpo repo no longer supported, https://github.com/menpo/conda-opencv3 ; now recommended to use conda-forge https://github.com/conda-forge/opencv-feedstock

Comment: @michael really the conda-forge is the right answer at this point and it is pretty much buried in antiquated answers. :(

Comment: I went ahead & added an update to this answer to remove `menpo`, and updated the syntax for installing `opencv` as per the `conda-forge` instructions.  The answer itself is not fundamentally changed, as `menpo` was just for installing "newer" opencv3, and we're already on opencv4.

Answer (score 16):

To install OpenCV in Anaconda, start up the Anaconda command prompt
and install OpenCV with

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo opencv3
```

Test that it works in your Anaconda Spyder or IPython console with

```
import cv2
```

You can also check the installed version using:

```
cv2.__version__
```

Comment: This worked for me on Win 10, 64 bit. Works in Spyder.

Comment: Works for opencv3 -> python[version='2.7.*|3.4.*|3.5.*']. Failed for Python 3.7.

Comment: @AMC I didn't use it. Anyways, is there a working method for 3.7?

Comment: @Nuhman Yes, you can get opencv from the official Anaconda channel, as well as from conda-forge ([here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv)).

Answer (score 10):

In my case, I've python 3.9
I did this in my conda env and it works :

```
pip install opencv-python==3.4.15.55
pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.15.55
```

Comment: On MacOS with Python3.9 I didn't need to qualify. I used `pip install opencv-python; pip install opencv-contrib-python`

Answer (score 9):

To install OpenCv with conda on Windows-64 and Python 3.5, the only one that worked for me is:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv=3.1.0
```

Answer (score 8):

I think the easiest option that should work cross-platform and across various versions of Anaconda is

```
#Run Anaconda Prompt as an Administrator (on Windows) & execute the command below
#(you may need to use   sudo   on a Unix-Based or Mac system 
#to have the needed permissions)

conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

Comment: Unless "System Administrator" is your job title and you are managing environments for others to use, you shouldn't be elevating privileges to use Conda. It only complicates the installation.

Answer (score 8):

it works on anaconda3 windows 10 I have already downloaded it at 5 December 2019.

Firstly, using this command:

> `pip install opencv-contrib-python`

after that windows will ask for permission and try again:

> `pip install opencv-contrib-python --user`

look at this it works!!

[image: openCV using anaconda]
[image: openCV using anaconda]

Comment: Is there any reason to do this instead of simply installing it from conda-forge? By the way, using the base environment for development is a bad idea, just don't touch it.

Comment: As of May 2022, using Anaconda 3 or newer, installing with conda-forge is the most straightforward.

Answer (score 7):

I had exactly the same problem, and could not get conda to install OpenCV. However, I managed to install it with the OpenCV installer you find at this site:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

His files are "Wheel" whl files that can be installed with pip, e.g.

pip install SomePackage-1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl

in a command window. It worked with Spyder directly after executing this command for me. I have had the same experience with other packages, the above UC Irvine site is a gold mine.

Answer (score 6):

I entered the following command in the command prompt:

```
conda install -c menpo opencv=2.4.11
```

This worked for me!!!

Comment: **Outdated answer.** The `menpo` channel is no longer actively maintained. Please consider updating.

Answer (score 6):

To insatll opencv without downgrading just hit out this in terminal
particularly the user of linux mint or Ubuntu based distro

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

Hence go with it I am pretty sure that this will not disappoint you.

Comment: This adds nothing that hasn't been said in earlier answers.

Answer (score 5):

On Linux, as discussed [here](https://github.com/conda-forge/opencv-feedstock/issues/43), the best way to get opencv at present is from loopbio at conda-forge:

```
conda install -c loopbio -c conda-forge -c pkgw-forge ffmpeg-feature ffmpeg gtk2 opencv
```

If you have 'a modern CPU' there exists also a compiled version "enabling all modern CPU instruction set extensions [...] and against libjpeg-turbo":

```
conda install -c loopbio -c conda-forge -c pkgw-forge ffmpeg-feature ffmpeg gtk2 opencv-turbo`
```

Two of the solutions mentioned in other answers don't work unconditionally:

- The conda you get through `conda install opencv` or `pip install opencv-python` doesn't have gtk2 support, so you can't display images through `imshow`.
- Conda built by Menpo (`conda install -c menpo opencv3`) has gtk2 support, but

  - they have only built OpenCV 3.2 for Python 3.5, not Python 3.6
  - Ubuntu 16.10 has deprecated `libpng12`, leading to a missing dependency and the following error when trying to `import cv2`: `ImportError: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`, as discussed [here](https://github.com/menpo/conda-opencv3/issues/20)

**EDIT:** @Yamaneko points out that as of 14 June 2017, "there is an issue with loopbio's OpenCV version 3.2.0. It silently fails to read and write videos. It is due to a combination of an upstream OpenCV issue in combination with an old GCC. More details [here](https://github.com/loopbio/opencv-feedstock/issues/6). There is a PR on its way to solve the issue."

Comment: +1 came here just to post this. However, one has to keep in mind that there is an issue with loopbio's OpenCV version 3.2.0 as of today. It silently fails to read and write videos. It is due to a combination of an upstream OpenCV issue in combination with an old GCC. More details [here](https://github.com/loopbio/opencv-feedstock/issues/6). There is a PR on its way to solve the issue.

Comment: This information is mostly outdated. Conda Forge coverage is more reliable these days and should be sufficient.

Answer (score 5):

I just installed conda 4.7.11 in Windows 10. OpenCV can be easily installed in Anaconda Navigator. After launching Navigator, click on *Environments* on the left panel. In the top drop-down, select *Not installed*. Then search for *py-opencv*, tick on the left checkbox to install it. It will install the dependent package *libopencv*. I use `import cv2` in Spyder to access it.

[image]

Comment: Nothing about this is specific or unique to Anaconda Navigator.

Answer (score 4):

Like others, I had issues with Python 3.5.1/Anaconda 2.4.0 on OS X 10.11..

But I found a compatible package here:

https://anaconda.org/menpo/opencv3

It can be installed via the command line like so:

```
 conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo opencv3
```

Worked like a charm. First time I've ever gotten OpenCV to work on 3.x!

Comment: **Outdated answer.** The `menpo` channel is no longer actively maintained.

Answer (score 4):

If `conda install opencv` or `conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv` does not work, you can try to compile from the source.

Download the source from http://opencv.org/downloads.html, follow the install instruction in http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html, (maybe you can jump to the last part directly, '*Building OpenCV from Source Using CMake...*), change the `cmake` command as following:

```
mkdir release
cd release
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/**/env/opencv-2.4.10 -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/home/**/env/anaconda/bin/python -D PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/**/env/anaconda/include/python2.7 -D PYTHON_LIBRARY=/home/**/env/anaconda/lib/libpython2.7.so -D PYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH=/home/**/env/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages -D PYTHON_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS=/home/**/env/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include ..

make -j4
make install
```

You will find cv2.so in `anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.

Then:

```
import cv2
print cv2.__version__
```

It will print out `2.4.10`.

My environment is GCC 4.4.6, Python 2.7 (anaconda), and opencv-2.4.10.

Answer (score 4):

To install the OpenCV package with conda, run:

```
conda install -c menpo opencv3=3.1.0
```

https://anaconda.org/menpo/opencv3

Comment: (this is duplicate existing answer, w/ edits, not sure which came first) menpo repo no longer supported, https://github.com/menpo/conda-opencv3 ; now recommended to use conda-forge https://github.com/conda-forge/opencv-feedstock

Comment: **Outdated answer.** The `menpo` channel is no longer actively maintained.

Answer (score 4):

**Windows only** solution. OpenCV 3.x pip install for Python 3.x

[Download .whl](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv) file (*cp*MN where you have Python M.N). *contrib* includes OpenCV-extra packages. For example, assuming you have Python 3.6 and Windows 64-bit, you might download opencv_python‑3.2.0+contrib‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl

From command prompt type:

```
pip install opencv_python‑3.2.0+contrib‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
```

You'll have a package in your `conda list` : `opencv-python 3.2.0+contrib <pip>`

Now you could test it (no errors):

```
>>> import cv2
>>>
```

Original source page where I took the information [is here](https://www.scivision.co/install-opencv-python-windows/).

Answer (score 4):

Although not through Conda, and this is specific to Ubuntu, the easiest way to install OpenCV with all its contrib modules built in such as SIFT and SURF is to use:

`pip install opencv-contrib-python`

It supports Python2.7+ and Python 3.4+

If you choose not to have the contribs built in, you could instead do:

`pip install opencv-python`

You need to install the following dependencies below before you run those commands though:

`sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake git libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev`

This is a good tutorial on setting OpenCV on Ubuntu:
https://medium.com/@debugvn/installing-opencv-3-3-0-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-7db376f93961

Answer (score 3):

An easy and straight forward solution is to install python3.5 first before installing opencv3

```
conda install python=3.5
```

followed by

```
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo opencv3
```

Comment: there is no `opencv3` it must be `opencv=3.1.0`

Comment: **Outdated answer.** The `menpo` channel is no longer actively maintained.

Answer (score 2):

The correct command for installing the current version of OpenCV 3.3 in Anaconda windows:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

or

```
conda install -c conda-forge/label/broken opencv
```

For 3.2 use this:

```
conda install -c menpo opencv3
```

Comment: **Do not use the `broken` tag!** That opens up the solver to use every package that has been tagged as `broken`. Conda package maintainers use that tag to *prevent* packages that have identified bugs in their build from being installed.

Answer (score 2):

I tried following command and it works fine

> conda install -c conda-forge opencv

once you hit the command it will ask for yes or no

[image]

If you select yes it will proceed and install all the required packages

Comment: This adds nothing that hasn't already been recommended previously (e.g., [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42027257/570918)).

Answer (score 2):

One thing i think nobody mentioned is that if you are using Windows N or KN edition, please install  [Media Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/mediafeaturepack)  that is used for OpenCV. 
Also make sure you have [Visual C++ Distributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145) 
installed.
And then you can use command

```
conda install -c menpo opencv
```

Comment: The opencv package from menpo is unmaintained since late 2017, possibly earlier. Combined with the fact that both the official/main Anaconda channel and conda-forge offer opencv, there hasn't been a reason to use this in years.

Comment: The above method worked for me when i was installing it about 6 months ago. `conda-forge` didn't worked for me.But thanks for providing the details info.

Answer (score 2):

This one worked best for me: I changed the Conda solver:

```
conda install -n base conda-libmamba-solver
```

And then installed opencv using:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

Installed in approx. 5-10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The following command works for me too. I am using an embedded IPython Notebook in Anaconda.

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv
```

Comment: **Outdated answer.** The `menpo` channel is no longer actively maintained.

Answer (score 1):

I have just tried on two Win32 Python 3.5 computers. At first, I was able to `conda install opencv`, but it didn't work nor did the version from menpp, but this did:

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/conda-forge opencv
```

Comment: Wow. `binstar` haven't seen that in years! Just `-c conda-forge` works these days.

Answer (score 1):

I had steps in [repo](https://github.com/Romeliigalbia/Face-Detection-with-Datasets-and-Training-for-Face-Recognition-Using-OpenCV3-Python3/blob/master/Follow%20This%20Steps%20Carefully) that will help you properly install OpenCV.

If the links if broken, see this.

For requirements and prerequisites follow this instructions:

YOU NEED TO HAVE WINDOWS OS to begin this project.

windows 7 to 10

Follow the steps carefully

1. Install Anaconda2 32/64 python 2

   or

   Install Anaconda3 32/64 python 3

   It Depends on System Information

   Along the way you must check all the options ignore the red text

   Then wait till installation completed ...

   Open CMD admin when finish installed

   Make sure that the anaconda-python is configured in CMD admin
2. Type: python

   This will come out:

   C:\WINDOWS\system32>python Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:27:45)

   [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
3. Next is to install packages:

   Numpy

   OpenCV

   PyMySQL or pymysql

   Install and Import OpenCV

   conda install -c conda-forge opencv = (version optional)

   (click yes if there's updates)

   Install and Import Numpy

   pip install numpy

   (click yes if there's updates)

   Install and Import PyMySQL/pymysql

   pip install PyMySQL or pymysql
4. When all the package is completely installed, then you must Reboot it.

   go to CMD admin again

   type "python"

   import cv2 (cv2 is OpenCV)

   import Numpy or numpy

   import pymysql

   import os

   from PIL from Image

   if all of then is ok.. your ready to run the code!!

   After you finish all the steps, you can now test the code in SPYDER python that I use

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18622902)

Comment: @Yaron. that's probably will happen in the future.

Comment: This seems unnecessarily lengthy. More importantly, why would you use pip to install libraries like NumPy?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install opencv 3.4.0, **there, unfortunately, is not** this version inside conda.   You need to use pip instead.

`pip install opencv-python==3.4.0.12`

Answer (score 0):

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo opencv
```

Try this

Comment: **Outdated answer.** The `menpo` channel is no longer actively maintained. Please considering updating answer.

Answer (score 0):

You just copy the cv2.pyd file to the `C:\Users\USERNAME\Anaconda2\Lib` directory.

You get the cv2.pyd file at this link (https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/).

The cv2.pyd is located at `C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\opencv\build\python\2.7\x64`.

Comment: Please do not casually recommend manually changing anything within Conda. Conda tightly orchestrates the management of dependencies. Manual tinkering can lead to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to update the brilliant [answer by Atlas7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23119413/how-do-i-install-python-opencv-through-conda/30281466#30281466).

If you're using OpenCV 3, change the test code to the following:

```
import cv2
cap=cv2.VideoCapture("input_video.mp4")
print cap.isOpened()   # True = read video successfully. False - fail to read video.

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))
print out.isOpened()  # True = write out video successfully. False - fail to write out video.

cap.release()
out.release()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general approach to using conda to install packages for Python that applies:

1. `conda search packageName`  e.g. `conda search opencv`
2. If this doesn't return results, `conda install packageName` will not work.
3. At this point you can go to, https://anaconda.org/ and type the packageName into the search box. If this pulls up results (which it should for OpenCV), then click on one of the results that is for your platform (e.g. win-64). The next page will show you the command to use to install this package (e.g. `conda install -c menpo opencv=2.4.11`).
4. If your package doesn't return results by search https://anaconda.org, then you can try `pip install packageName`.

Caution: when I used step 3 to install OpenCV for win-64, I got an error when I tried to `import cv2`.

Here is the error:

```
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version a but this version of numpy is 9
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
```

ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

I think the error is due to package version conflicts. Nevertheless, this is a valid way to install OpenCV and other Python packages, you just might need to resolve some package version conflicts.

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? It offers helpful advice beyond the  numerous silly dupes of "conda install --c menpo opencv" that keep getting upvoted. May I suggest to remove or review the Caution part, because it does not add value, only clutter.

Answer (score 0):

Try following these commands in this order:-

```
conda update anaconda-navigator
conda update navigator-updater
pip install opencv-python
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem, but I have solved it now. This is what I did:

First enter `conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv` in the command prompt and then find the path `Anaconda\pkgs\opencv-2.4.9.1-np19py27_0\Lib\site-packages`. Now copy all the files present here into `Anaconda\Lib\site-packages`. Now you will be able to use OpenCV with Python.

Comment: First, `menpo` is no longer maintained, so this answer is outdated. Second, please do not casually recommend manually adding files into Conda environments. Conda tightly orchestrates the management of environments. Manual tinkering can lead to undefined behavior.

Answer (score -1):

I installed it like this:

```
$ conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge opencv
```

I tried `conda install opencv` directly, but it does not work for me since I am using Python 3.5 which is higher version that default OpenCV library in conda. Later, I tried 'anaconda/opencv', but it does not work either. I found finally that conda-forge/opencv works for Python 3.5.

Comment: This information was already present in earlier answers. Please consider updating and commenting on those instead.

Answer (score -1):

Windows 7, conda 4.4.10 python 2.7.6
Downloaded opencv package from Unofficial Windows Binaries for python extensions packages. (picked python 2.4 AMD 64)
cd Download
pip install opencv_python...
python run_some.py (where import cv2 ...) seems to work.
YMMV

Answer (score -1):

i was on MAC machine inside one of anaconda virutal environment. For me,

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

worked fine.

It installed opencv version **3.4.4**

Hope it helps.

Comment: This information was already available in earlier answers. Please consider upvoting those instead.

Answer (score -2):

Following command adds a different anaconda channel for `opencv3`, you should be able to pull from it.

```
conda install --channel  https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/menpo opencv3
```

Comment: The opencv package from menpo is unmaintained since late 2017, possibly earlier. Combined with the fact that both the official/main Anaconda channel and conda-forge offer opencv, there hasn't been a reason to use this in years.

Answer (score -4):

Using Wheel files is an easier approach. If you cannot install Wheel files from the command prompt, you can use an executable pip file which exists in the <Anaconda path>/Scripts folder.