# Is cv2.cv missing in OpenCV 3.0?

Tags: opencv3.0

I've just installed OpenCV 3  on Win7 for using with Python 2.7. 
I've copied cv2.pyd to /DLLs.

Unfortunately many examples I've tried, don't work, because cv2.cv seems to be missing in OpenCV3

Is there a replacement for it? Is there a table of new constant-names used to be declared in cv2.cv?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes, the deprecated cv2.cv was removed in opencv3.0

something similar to:

```
import cv2

help(cv2)
```

will give you a (looong) list of the api's content.

Comment: depends on [where you look](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html)

Answer (score 2):

To get old examples to work, you need to create/edit a file cv.py in site-packages with the following single line of text:

```
import cv2 as cv
```

Comment: OK I tried this briefly - had some success but then started writing fresh code for cv2 - was easier than trying to get old code that imported cv2.cv working.

Answer (score 0):

Its not there in 3. Only cv2 is present.And also instead of functions being `cv.something` its now cv2.You can `import cv2` and check the changes.