# Is there no more module cv for opencv python?

Tags: python, opencv

The solutions on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45675823/no-module-named-cv) do not work with the opencv python version 3.3.1. `cv2.__version__` prints `3.3.1-dev`, and even `import cv2.cv` returns the no module error.

On reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417108/what-is-different-between-all-these-opencv-python-interfaces) it seems like both the `cv2` and `cv` interfaces were maintained, at least for a while but that doesn't seem the case any more.

So...

1. Does the cv module exist any more?
2. If not, then from which opencv version was this lost? And where can we find old cv functions? For instance `cv.StereoRectify`

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenCV 3.x cv was [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132081/is-cv2-cv-missing-in-opencv-3-0).
Some old cv modules can be found in cv2, as `cv2.stereoRectify`, others are not in opencv installation anymore due to legal concerns.

You may need to `pip install opencv-contrib-python --user`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the old `cv` module has been completely removed from OpenCV in version 3.

Old functions should have been ported to the current `cv2` module. In your case, it seems `cv.StereoRectify` is now [`cv2.stereoRectify`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga617b1685d4059c6040827800e72ad2b6)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. Was wondering if there were any notes released regarding this port. I found some documentation but it's not always got python notes [like here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=stereocalibrate#stereocalibrate)