# How do I get opencv for python3 with anaconda3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

So, initially, I just had python 3.5 from the anaconda installation and all was fine.  Then I was following a tutorial that suggested the use of enthought canopy, which used python 2.7. 
After this I did a 'pip install opencv-python' and that installed the 2.7 version of the library.  I should note, I am on Ubunutu 16 desktop for development.

I cannot seem to find a way for installing opencv and possibly cv2 for python3, the version installed in my user directory.  Maybe I should remove enthought canopy.  But I will still need to find the correct versions of opencv, cv2 for anaconda3.
Thanks in advance for any help,
Bruce

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23119413/1165522

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install python opencv through Conda?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23119413/how-to-install-python-opencv-through-conda)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have anaconda installed, try the following (as seen in [this tutorial](https://rivercitylabs.org/up-and-running-with-opencv3-and-python-3-anaconda-edition/)):

```
conda create -n opencv numpy scipy scikit-learn matplotlib python=3
source activate opencv
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv3
```

it will first create a virtual environment called `opencv` with the packages `opencv`, `numpy`, `scipy`, `scikit-learn` and `matplotlib`.

It works for me on Mac.