# python cv2.Videocapture() does not work, cap.isOpened() returns false

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

cv2.Videocapture() works fine while using webcam but while trying to read from hard drive it shows error  cap.isOpened() returns false

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
background=cv2.imread('background.png')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('car video.mp4')
cap.open('car video.mp4')
print cap.isOpened()
while 1:
    ret,img=cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('a',img)
    print img.shape


    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It shows this error

```
    cv2.imshow('a',img)
    error: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:266: error:       (-215)        size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow
```

my opencv version 3.0.0, python 2.7, windows10 32 bit

Comment: Firstly, remove cap.open() call; it's redundant. Second, check if your video is in the same directory as your code. Third, remove the space in its filename. Try car_video.mp4

Comment: I change file name and remove cap.open() . but error message remains same

Comment: enclose filename in double quotes

Comment: This link helps me a lot and solve my issue.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23119413/how-to-install-python-opencv-through-conda

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need the ffmpeg codec to be able to read the video.

Comment: yes it's works thanks. At first i didn't copy the ffmpeg codec file

Comment: could you please tell me how to add ffmpeg codec file?

Comment: Copy all the file from **OpenCV\3rdparty\ffmpeg\**   to **C:\Python27\** or to a directory that is in the PATH. 

Renaming the opencv_ffmpeg.dll file may also be necessary.

For OpenCV version X.Y.Z
opencv_ffmpeg.dll ==> opencv_ffmpegXYZ.dll

For 64-bit OpenCV version X.Y.Z
opencv_ffmpeg.dll ==> opencv_ffmpegXYZ_64.dll

Comment: i am using opencv 3.0.0 and win 32 so rename the file just like this  opencv_ffmpeg300.dll

Answer (score 6):

I was getting the same error while using opencv in anaconda3 virtual environment. 
I checked the buildinformation for current opencv version and ffmpeg was marked **"no"**.

To resolve this

1. I uninstalled opencv from my conda environment (conda uninstall  opencv)
2. Installed latest ffmpeg using conda-forge channel (conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg)

   Name                    Version                   Build  Channel

   ffmpeg                    4.0.2                ha6a6e2b_0    conda-forge
3. Then installed opencv again using conda-forge channel (conda install -c conda-forge opencv)

   Name                    Version                   Build  Channel

opencv                    3.4.1           py36_blas_openblash829a850_201  [blas_openblas]  conda-forge

**Restart the python console after doing this and import cv2.**

Comment: To check the build information: `python -c "import cv2; print(cv2.getBuildInformation())"`

Answer (score 5):

try

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

It worked for me

Comment: for issues with pygame's webcam module, this made things *worse*

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that you are writing your file name correctly. I've never seen a file directory like **'car video.mp4'**. When you are using the zero based index your webcam and cv2.VideoCapture works fine; however VideoCapture cannot read a file like **'car(space)video.mp4'** A working code is something like this;

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')

while(cap.isOpened()):

    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret==True:

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```