# Failed to run conda install -c menpo opencv3=3.2.0 in Windows7

Tags: opencv, anaconda

I want to update opencv from 3.1.0 to 3.2.0

I run "conda install -c menpo opencv3=3.1.0" to install opencv 3.1.0

when I run "conda install -c menpo opencv3=3.2.0", I got error.

```
C:\Users\eason>conda install -c menpo opencv3=3.2.0
Fetching package metadata .............


PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: '' Package missing in current win-64 ch
annels:
- opencv3 3.2.0*

You can search for packages on anaconda.org with

anaconda search -t conda opencv3
```

https://anaconda.org/menpo/opencv3

When I run "anaconda search -t conda opencv3"...
[image]

I found opencv3=3.2.0 , but I can't install it?

Is anyone helps ?  thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

run the following command

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv=3.2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The [menpo file page](https://anaconda.org/menpo/opencv3/files) shows only *OpenCV 3.2.0* for *Python 2.7/3.4/3.5* on *linux-64* platform is available.

If you are using Python 3.4, you may try this:

```
conda install -c daleydeng opencv=3.2.0
```

Comment: UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:

  - opencv 3.2.0* -> python ==3.5
  - python 2.7*

Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.

Comment: I read the menpo file page... I'm using win7...OK,It can't install... Thanks!

Comment: If you can tell you are using 32-bit or 64-bit Windows, Win7 or Win10 doesn't matter, may be someone can help to advise if there is a binary/package fits you.

Comment: I'm using Win7 64

Answer (score 1):

Just pushed my OpenCV 3.2 binary to [github](https://github.com/CCM2016/opencv-3.2.0_binary). It compiled with opencv_contrib modules and runs on Win10 64-bit with Python 2.7.

You may have a trial. Good Luck!

Comment: What are the installation paths of your 1) Anaconda and 2) OpenCV3.2.0? Do you use `conda-env` in your Anaconda setup?

Comment: You may refer to **Atlas7**'s reply in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23119413](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23119413/how-to-install-python-opencv-through-conda?rq=1). The `cv2.pyd` and `OPENCV_DIR` setup is pretty much the same. The difference is that my `OpenCV 3.2.0` binary with `contrib` modules is complied with VC14 (i.e. Visual Studio 2015) instead of VC12 (i.e. Visual Studio 2013).

Comment: I tried it. the same result. When  updating the cv2 from 3.1.0 to 3.2.0,I got DLL load failed.

Comment: Seems there is some setting conflicts. What are the Windows environment variable settings and.install paths of your OpenCV 3.2, Anaconda/Python 2.7 and ...?

Comment: Opencv: C:\Program Files\OpenCV 3.2.0  .  Windows environment:    C:\Program Files\OpenCV 3.2.0\x64\vc14;   I think it's right.

Comment: Have you defined this `OPENCV_DIR = C:\Program Files\OpenCV 3.2.0\×64\vc14` and added this `%OPENCV_DIR%\bin` to Windows environment? For `cv2.pyd`, has it been copied to `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages` (per your screenshot above)?

Comment: Added it ... and  got the same result.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Anaconda terminal
2. Navigate to the folder in Anaconda main folder which contains Python Scripts
3. Download the un-offical opencv + contrib binaries from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv)
4. In the Anaconda terminal do pip install

Comment: opencv_python-3.2.0+contrib-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on
 this platform.

Comment: I'm using python 2.7. I think it's not support opencv3.2.0 ?

Comment: The package name tells it's for Python 3.5  -  "opencv_python-3.2.0+contrib-**cp35**-cp35m-win_amd64".

Comment: @eason ...whats the harm in upgrading to python3.6 or python3.5 ?

Comment: I won't upgrade python version,I'm in a company.