# Unable to install OpenCV 3.2 in Anaconda 4.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, anaconda, conda

Tried the following steps

1. `conda install -c menpo opencv3=3.2.0` ..
    Fetching package metadata....An unexpected error has occurred
2. Did some internet search and used `conda config --set ssl_verify=False`
3. Then tried doing `conda update -all` and `conda update pyopenssl` but no luck
4. even `remove certifi`does not work ...gives the same error...infact any      update / install attempt gives the same result.
5. I have **NOT** set my `PYTHONHOME` or `PYTHONPATH`
6. Followin are the screen shots of my current conda settings and the update/install error. Platform : Windows 8.1
7. If there is any other method to install OpenCV 3.2 in Anaconda environment please mention it

**EDIT : PROBLEM SOLVED**

1. Open Anaconda terminal
2. Navigate to the folder in Anaconda main folder which contains Python Scripts
3. Download the un-offical opencv + contrib binaries from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grwGk.png)
4. In the Anaconda terminal do pip install

[image: conda install error]

`[image: current conda settings]

Answer (score 2):

For anaconda running python 3.7, you can use

```
conda install py-opencv=3.4.2
```

Answer (score 1):

The [menpo file page](https://anaconda.org/menpo/opencv3/files) shows only OpenCV 3.2.0 for Python 2.7/3.4/3.5 on linux-64 platform is available.

You can try this OpenCV 3.2.0 binary in [github](https://github.com/CCM2016/opencv-3.2.0_binary) if your Windows is 64-bit and with Python 2.7.

See this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42310099](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42310099/failed-to-run-conda-install-c-menpo-opencv3-3-2-0-in-windows7/42535587?noredirect=1#comment72270852_42535587) for more informtion.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can go into your Anaconda environment and run one of the following for OpenCV 3.4.4:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv 
conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 opencv 
conda install -c conda-forge/label/broken opencv 
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 opencv
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create a new environment using the anaconda navigator with python 3.5. It works for me in that environment.