# cv2.VideoCapture and ffmpeg

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

How I can use ffmpeg to read a video through OpenCV? This my code:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("input2.mp4")
ret = cap.read()
print ret
```

The result is `(False, None)`.

I set up OpenCV through Anaconda.

Comment: Does the video exist in the working directory?

Comment: yes, the video is exist in the working directory

Comment: This link helps me a lot
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23119413/how-to-install-python-opencv-through-conda

Comment: I was facing the same issue. I had opencv installed in my envirenment. I installed opencv-python and it worked for me. pip install opencv-python.

Comment: I was facing the same issue. I had opencv installed in my envirenment. I installed opencv-python and it worked for me. pip install opencv-python.

Answer (score 3):

I got the error while read a h264 mp4 sometimes. The ffmpeg has more codec than cv2 that may solve the reading problem. You can use this pkg, which is similar to cv2 in API.

```py
#!pip install ffmpegcv
import ffmpegcv
vfile_in = 'A.mp4'
vfile_out = 'A_h264.mp4'
vidin = ffmpegcv.VideoCapture(vfile_in)
w, h = vidin.width, vidin.height
vidout = ffmpegcv.VideoWriter(vfile_out, 'h264_nvenc', vidin.fps, (w, h))

for frame in vidin:
    vidout.write(frame)

vidin.release()
vidout.release()
```

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you using? OpenCV is not compiled with FFMPEG which is the video codec library for Linux and OSX as described [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python) . So you have to build OpenCV with FFMPEG manually.
[This](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html) will guide you with the building process. But the building process can be tricky with issues as the building environments differ from each other. I recommend using a docker container for running the code like [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/valian/docker-python-opencv-ffmpeg/).