# How do I install openCV via anaconda at mac ?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I get error

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
```

- opencv -> numpy 1.7* -> python 2.6* -> openssl 1.0.1*
  - python 3.6*
Use "conda info " to see the dependencies for each package.

my conda list

```
# packages in environment at /Users/robiulislam/anaconda:
```

#
_license                  1.1                      py36_1
alabaster                 0.7.9                    py36_0
anaconda                  4.3.0               np111py36_0
anaconda-client           1.6.0                    py36_0
anaconda-navigator        1.4.3                    py36_0
appdirs                   1.4.0                     
appnope                   0.1.0                    py36_0
appscript                 1.0.1                    py36_0
astroid                   1.4.9                    py36_0
astropy                   1.3                 np111py36_0
babel                     2.3.4                    py36_0
backports                 1.0                      py36_0
beautifulsoup4            4.5.3                    py36_0
bitarray                  0.8.1                    py36_0
blaze                     0.10.1                   py36_0
bokeh                     0.12.4                   py36_0
boto                      2.45.0                   py36_0
bottleneck                1.2.0               np111py36_0
cffi                      1.9.1                    py36_0
chardet                   2.3.0                    py36_0
chest                     0.2.3                    py36_0
click                     6.7                      py36_0
cloudpickle               0.2.2                    py36_0
clyent                    1.2.2                    py36_0
colorama                  0.3.7                    py36_0
conda                     4.3.13                   py36_0
conda-env                 2.6.0                         0
configobj                 5.0.6                    py36_0
contextlib2               0.5.4                    py36_0
cryptography              1.7.1                    py36_0
curl                      7.52.1                        0
cycler                    0.10.0                   py36_0
cython                    0.25.2                   py36_0
cytoolz                   0.8.2                    py36_0
dask                      0.13.0                   py36_0
datashape                 0.5.4                    py36_0
decorator                 4.0.11                   py36_0
dill                      0.2.5                    py36_0
Django                    1.10.5                    
docutils                  0.13.1                   py36_0
entrypoints               0.2.2                    py36_0
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                    py36_0
fastcache                 1.0.2                    py36_1
flask                     0.12                     py36_0
flask-cors                3.0.2                    py36_0
freetype                  2.5.5                         2
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                    py36_0
gevent                    1.2.1                    py36_0
greenlet                  0.4.11                   py36_0
h5py                      2.6.0               np111py36_2
hdf5                      1.8.17                        1
heapdict                  1.0.0                    py36_1
icu                       54.1                          0
idna                      2.2                      py36_0
imagesize                 0.7.1                    py36_0
ipykernel                 4.5.2                    py36_0
ipython                   5.1.0                    py36_1
ipython_genutils          0.1.0                    py36_0
ipywidgets                5.2.2                    py36_1
isort                     4.2.5                    py36_0
itsdangerous              0.24                     py36_0
jbig                      2.1                           0
jdcal                     1.3                      py36_0
jedi                      0.9.0                    py36_1
jinja2                    2.9.4                    py36_0
jpeg                      9b                            0
jsonschema                2.5.1                    py36_0
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py36_3
jupyter_client            4.4.0                    py36_0
jupyter_console           5.0.0                    py36_0
jupyter_core              4.2.1                    py36_0
Keras                     1.2.1                     
lazy-object-proxy         1.2.2                    py36_0
libiconv                  1.14                          0
libpng                    1.6.27                        0
libtiff                   4.0.6                         3
libxml2                   2.9.4                         0
libxslt                   1.1.29                        0
llvmlite                  0.15.0                   py36_0
locket                    0.2.0                    py36_1
lxml                      3.7.2                    py36_0
markupsafe                0.23                     py36_2
matplotlib                2.0.0               np111py36_0
mistune                   0.7.3                    py36_1
mkl                       2017.0.1                      0
mkl-service               1.1.2                    py36_3
mpmath                    0.19                     py36_1
multipledispatch          0.4.9                    py36_0
nbconvert                 4.2.0                    py36_0
nbformat                  4.2.0                    py36_0
networkx                  1.11                     py36_0
nltk                      3.2.2                    py36_0
nose                      1.3.7                    py36_1
notebook                  4.3.1                    py36_0
numba                     0.30.1              np111py36_0
numexpr                   2.6.1               np111py36_2
numpy                     1.11.3                   py36_0
numpy                     1.12.0                    
numpydoc                  0.6.0                    py36_0
odo                       0.5.0                    py36_1
openpyxl                  2.4.1                    py36_0
openssl                   1.0.2k                        0
packaging                 16.8                      
pandas                    0.19.2              np111py36_1
partd                     0.3.7                    py36_0
path.py                   10.0                     py36_0
pathlib2                  2.2.0                    py36_0
patsy                     0.4.1                    py36_0
pep8                      1.7.0                    py36_0
pexpect                   4.2.1                    py36_0
pickleshare               0.7.4                    py36_0
pillow                    4.0.0                    py36_0
pip                       9.0.1                    py36_1
ply                       3.9                      py36_0
prompt_toolkit            1.0.9                    py36_0
psutil                    5.0.1                    py36_0
ptyprocess                0.5.1                    py36_0
py                        1.4.32                   py36_0
pyasn1                    0.1.9                    py36_0
pycosat                   0.6.1                    py36_1
pycparser                 2.17                     py36_0
pycrypto                  2.6.1                    py36_4
pycurl                    7.43.0                   py36_2
pyflakes                  1.5.0                    py36_0
pygments                  2.1.3                    py36_0
pylint                    1.6.4                    py36_1
pyopenssl                 16.2.0                   py36_0
pyparsing                 2.1.4                    py36_0
pyparsing                 2.1.10                    
pyqt                      5.6.0                    py36_1
pytables                  3.3.0               np111py36_0
pytest                    3.0.5                    py36_0
python                    3.6.0                         0
python-dateutil           2.6.0                    py36_0
python.app                1.2                      py36_4
pytz                      2016.10                  py36_0
pyyaml                    3.12                     py36_0
pyzmq                     16.0.2                   py36_0
qt                        5.6.2                         0
qtawesome                 0.4.3                    py36_0
qtconsole                 4.2.1                    py36_1
qtpy                      1.2.1                    py36_0
readline                  6.2                           2
redis                     3.2.0                         0
redis-py                  2.10.5                   py36_0
requests                  2.12.4                   py36_0
rope                      0.9.4                    py36_1
ruamel_yaml               0.11.14                  py36_1
scikit-image              0.12.3              np111py36_1
scikit-learn              0.18.1              np111py36_1
scipy                     0.18.1              np111py36_1
seaborn                   0.7.1                    py36_0
setuptools                27.2.0                   py36_0
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py36_1
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py36_0
sip                       4.18                     py36_0
six                       1.10.0                   py36_0
snowballstemmer           1.2.1                    py36_0
sockjs-tornado            1.0.3                    py36_0
sphinx                    1.5.1                    py36_0
spyder                    3.1.2                    py36_0
sqlalchemy                1.1.5                    py36_0
sqlite                    3.13.0                        0
statsmodels               0.6.1               np111py36_1
sympy                     1.0                      py36_0
terminado                 0.6                      py36_0
Theano                    0.8.2                     
tk                        8.5.18                        0
toolz                     0.8.2                    py36_0
tornado                   4.4.2                    py36_0
traitlets                 4.3.1                    py36_0
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py36_0
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py36_0
werkzeug                  0.11.15                  py36_0
wheel                     0.29.0                   py36_0
widgetsnbextension        1.2.6                    py36_0
wrapt                     1.10.8                   py36_0
xlrd                      1.0.0                    py36_0
xlsxwriter                0.9.6                    py36_0
xlwings                   0.10.2                   py36_0
xlwt                      1.2.0                    py36_0
xz                        5.2.2                         1
yaml                      0.1.6                         0
zlib                      1.2.8                         3

it has numpy 1.12 and python 3.6

Comment: This post may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23119413/how-to-install-python-opencv-through-conda

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Activate conda enviorment
2. **pip install opencv-python**

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions below to install python2 + OpenCV in mac

http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/11/28/macos-install-opencv-3-and-python-2-7/

In case of python3 + OpenCV follow

http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/05/macos-install-opencv-3-and-python-3-5/

This instruction worked for me

If you still have problem search for OpenCV **precompiled** pack and use it with python

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you have a numpy greater than 1.7