# Installing OpenCV 3.0 in Anaconda (Python 3.5)

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, conda

I am trying to work with opencv 3.0 on my Mac OS 10.12.6
I am working with Anaconda in a python 3.5 environment, and have tried the following command in terminal:

> conda install -c jlaura OpenCV3

from the following: https://anaconda.org/search?q=platform%3Aosx-64%20opencv3

However, this ends up giving the following output/error:

PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

- opencv3 -> tbb

We have searched for the packages in the following channels:
   (This is followed by a number of links, which stack overflow will not let me post as I don't have enough rep yet)

What is the best way to get opencv 3.0 on conda with a python 3.5 environment?

I need this because I am trying to implement the following: https://github.com/datitran/object_detector_app

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install python opencv through Conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23119413/how-to-install-python-opencv-through-conda)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I have seen that thread and it point to conda install -c menpo opencv, which is for opencv 3.2

Answer (score 1):

I essentially had to reinstall python 3.5 using:

> conda install python=3.5

and then get the opencv 3.0 version like so:

> conda install -c jlaura opencv3

And that did it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same problem, trying to use the same repo, however the above did not work for me. Eventually I was able to download openCV 3.0.0 by running

```
conda install -c memex opencv
```

If this has for some reason deprecated, you can always search for another option on the [anaconda cloud website](https://anaconda.org/search?q=opencv). Just ctrl-f for `3.0.0` and find a package that includes your platform (osx in my case).