# Unable to find SIFT or xfeatures2d in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0

I recently switch back to python for facial detection and pattern recognition using OpenCV 3.4.1 However when running OpenCV for point recongnition, I get the error

```
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'SIFT_create'
```

I have read that changing the line from `sift =  cv2.SIFT_create()` to `sift =  sift =  cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()` should solve this.

However I get an error

```
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'xfeatures2d'.
```

Shouldnt xfeatures2d be included in OpenCV? Any suggestion on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50469642/9709132
This is what solved it for me.
Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you installed `opencv-python` with pip. That package does not include contributed modules. To fix, uninstall `opencv-python` and install `opencv-contrib-python` instead.