# How can I install Open CV after I installed Python 3?

Tags: python, opencv, installation, anaconda

I downloaded and install Anaconda 3 on my computer windows and now I'd like to add OpenCV.

What's the easiest way to do it ?

Comment: conda install -c menpo opencv    ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23119413/how-do-i-install-python-opencv-through-conda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I do it on windows:

1. Open your `anaconda prompt`
2. Select your environment `activate my_env` (for base env skip this step)
3. Install opencv using `pip install opencv-python`
4. Further install additional pkgs using `pip install opencv-contrib-python`