# I cannot install cv2 in python, how can I install cv2?

Tags: python, opencv

I got the ModuleNotFoundError and cannot install cv2. What to do now?

I tried to download cv2 using pip and I got this error

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cv2 (from versions: none).

Answer (score 1):

you can install opencv using this

```
    pip install opencv-python
```

now opencv gets installed

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install the package?

```
conda install -c menpo opencv
```

Reference: [How do I install Python OpenCV through Conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23119413/how-do-i-install-python-opencv-through-conda)