# How could I install OpenCV in Python without errors?

Tags: python, windows, opencv, spyder

I am trying to use OpenCV for a script written in Python/Spyder.
I need the latest 4.9.0 version of OpenCV. When I try to import cv2, I repeatedly get an error:

```
*Could Not Find C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\Library\etc\OpenCL\vendors\temp.txt* 
I have Windows 10, miniconda. I installed OpenCV using
*conda install -c conda-forge opencv*
```

I tried removing OpenCV by
*conda remove opencv*
and reinstalling it, and it did not help.

Comment: using python pip always works:  `python -m pip install opencv-python`

Comment: here is the link: https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Python OpenCV through Conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23119413/how-do-i-install-python-opencv-through-conda)

Answer (score 0):

Try below command,

`conda install -c menpo opencv`

 
Here is the link of similar issue: [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23119413/how-do-i-install-python-opencv-through-conda)

Hope this will help.

Comment: It worked, thanks! I managed to install OpenCV, but now I have a problem with the verions. I need 4.9.0, and when I run
conda list
it shows me that I have opencv 4.9.0. However, when I run
import cv2
cv2.__version__
I get 4.7.0 - both in Spyder and in Jupyther.