# How to run a python program in one folder and import and run a python program from another folder

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

Good evening.

I have scriptone.py in folderone and scripttwo.py in foldertwo.

How do I tell scriptone.py to run scripttwo.py from foldertwo

If both scriptone.py and scripttwo.py are in the same folder I can run scripttwo.py with

```
import scripttwo
```

But I would really like to run scripttwo.py from foldertwo

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the environmental variable `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it in the past:

```
import os
os.chdir('../foldertwo')
import sys
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())

import scripttwo
```

This adds the parent folder to the `path` variable, which holds all the places that Python looks for module when you use `import`.

Comment: In foldertwo a scripttwo.pyo file is created after running. why is this, what is it for and can it be deleted after running the script?

Comment: @SimonJeal: I don't typically see `.pyo` files, so I'm not totally sure why that would be. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8822335/1473772) should help.

Comment: Thanks I just read that. Im going to go with I can delete it, as my scripttwo.py will always change. thanks

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Adjuct

I used

```
import sys

secondscript = path/to/second/script
sys.path.append(secondscript)

import scripttwo
```

Working Solved.

By using sys.path.append() it tells python that there is another place to look for a script. So when you

```
import scripttwo
```

it knows to look in the appended location also.
Thank you for the advice