# Do modules have types in Python?

Tags: python, python-module

I'm reading [PEP338](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/) .Some words confused me:

> If the module is found, and is of **type** *PY_SOURCE* or *PY_COMPILED* , then the command line is effectively reinterpreted from `python <options> -m <module> <args>` to `python <options> <filename> <args>` .

Do modules have types in Python?

Comment: There are *types of modules*, in that they were sourced from a bytecompiled cache file or from source. The word *type* is not the same thing as the class of an object.

Comment: See about python file extensions http://stackoverflow.com/a/18032741/6575931

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modules can be loaded from *different sources*. The author refers to 2 specific sources the module was loaded from, see the [`imp` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html):

> `imp.PY_SOURCE`
>   The module was found as a source file.
>
> [...]
>
> `imp.PY_COMPILED`
>   The module was found as a compiled code object file.
>
> [...]
>
> `imp.C_EXTENSION`
>   The module was found as dynamically loadable shared library.

These values are used in the return value of the [`imp.get_suffixes()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html#imp.get_suffixes), among others.

The PEP states that only modules loaded from source (`.py` files) and from a bytecode cache file (`.pyc`) are supported; the `-m` switch does not support C extension modules (typically `.so` or `.dll` dynamically loaded libraries).

The resulting module object is still just a module object; the word *type* in the text you found is not referring Python's type system.

Answer (score 1):

The **type of module** means the **type of the file** where the module is stored, as python files have some possible types (and extensions.

The most common are compiled python files (**pyc** extension) or the regular, python plain source (**py**).

There are many other **py** file extensions, see the (almost) full list here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18032741/6575931.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the link [PEP338](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/#proposed-semantics)

> **Proposed Semantics** 
>   The semantics proposed are fairly simple: if -m is
>   used to execute a module the PEP 302 **import mechanisms** are used to
>   locate the module and retrieve its compiled code, before executing the
>   module in accordance with the semantics for a top-level module.

Now let us refer to the documentation of imp (the import mechanism) and determine the different types of modules that can be imported
[imp.get_suffixes()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.get_suffixes)

> **imp.get_suffixes()** Return a list of 3-element tuples, each describing
>   a particular type of module. Each triple has the form (suffix, mode,
>   type), where suffix is a string to be appended to the module name to
>   form the filename to search for, mode is the mode string to pass to
>   the built-in open() function to open the file (this can be 'r' for
>   text files or 'rb' for binary files), and **type is the file type,
>   which has one of the values PY_SOURCE, PY_COMPILED, or C_EXTENSION,
>   described below.**

and subsequently it explains what the different types are

> **imp.PY_SOURCE** The module was found as a source file.
>
> **imp.PY_COMPILED** The module was found as a compiled code object file.
>
> **imp.C_EXTENSION** The module was found as dynamically loadable shared
>   library.

So, the types mentioned in PEP 338 are nothing but the types of modules that can be imported and of these only PY_SOURCE or PY_COMPILED are the only two types out of the above three the command line is effectively reinterpreted from python  -m   to python    .

Comment: Thanks for your nice help,and your answer is great too.