# What is the .py{} extension?

Tags: python, git, gitignore, pypy

I found `*.py{}` in a `.gitignore` file and I am wondering what this extension is.

Found [here.](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/.gitignore#L28)

And [here.](https://codeberg.org/biotite-dev/biotite/src/commit/1882a661f00f3368b6b3dc71bb6eb33c5be0003d/.gitignore)

PS. The git commit mentioned pypy.

Comment: It says right above it that it is a compiled python file extension

Comment: `.py{}` is not a standard extension, though. Either this is an error in the file, or their build process does something really unusual.

Comment: @DetectivePikachu There is .pyc, .pyo, and .pyc for compiled Python. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822335/what-do-the-python-file-extensions-pyc-pyd-pyo-stand-for However, I can find nowhere information about .py{}.

Comment: I could also find it here: https://codeberg.org/biotite-dev/biotite/src/commit/1882a661f00f3368b6b3dc71bb6eb33c5be0003d/.gitignore

Comment: The comment of the commit that added that ignore rule states "Ignore *.py{} and *.py-e files (from PyPy?)"

Comment: My best guess was this was supposed to be a brace expansion, but for some reason was left empty. Or they have some bizarre obscure or custom testing suite that makes these extensions. I dunno. You'd have to ask the authors. The git blame mentions PyPy, so maybe they were writing some kind of custom interpreter? Its odd in any case

Comment: Git's ignore files don't do any sort of brace expansion, so `*.py{c,o}` would be taken literally, rather than being a shortcut for `*.pyc` and `*.pyo`.

Comment: The number of "what does X do?" questions we have in this knowledgebase, where X is completely useless code that was introduced as a bug in some random 3rd-party library...

Comment: ...indeed, I'd argue that that's one of the places where there's value in enforcing our rules that questions must be about "a problem you actually face", as opposed to a point of curiosity or trivia.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Well, this question actually came from a problem I was facing when using ripgrep on the Biopython repo. Apparently this specific pattern is interpreted by the globbing system of ripgrep causing all *.py files to be ignored. That's a ripgrep bug. Funny how two seemingly minor bugs made me completely lost on the real problem I was dealing with with the actual Python code. Luckily, there was still good ol' grep -R, to bring me to the right file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't a *common* file extension, but the braces `{}` are used in globs (like regex) for pattern recognition. From this [link on globs](https://facelessuser.github.io/wcmatch/glob/), it is

> Bash style brace expansions. This is applied to patterns before
>   anything else.

Though it's left empty so I'm not sure that it does anything of use in this case.

Comment: What does that link have to do with `.gitignore` files?

Comment: The point is whomever wrote this gitignore appears to have been attempting to do a glob. Though in your comment you mention that git doesn't do expansion so to answer the OP's question: it *isn't* a file extension

Comment: You are *assuming* that's what they're trying, and only in that Python library are globs and brace expansions lumped into the same category.

Comment: It *could* be a file extension. Create a file named `foo.py{}`, and per that pattern, Git will ignore it.

Comment: Yes it can be a file extension, but it's not some common file extension which seems to be what OP was asking about - so yes I should have worded my response more carefully. As @DetectivePikachu pointed out, it could be for some strange test suite (or just a mistake), but it's not some *common* file extension.