# Python cannot find Boost.Python module

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I try to create a simple C++ module for python with Boost, but python gives me `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MyLib'`.
The .py file is in the same location as MyLib.dll.

UPD: if i change dll to pyd or replace `add_library(MyLib MODULE MyLib.cpp)` with `PYTHON_ADD_MODULE(MyLib MyLib.cpp)` I get another error: `ImportError: DLL load failed while importing MyLib: The specified module could not be found.`

CMake

```
set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS TRUE)
set(BOOST_ROOT "C:/local/boost_1_80_0")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_MODULE_PREFIX "")

find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS python310 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_library(MyLib MODULE MyLib.cpp)

target_link_libraries(MyLib ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

C++

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

    auto* get()
    {
        return "Hello from C++";
    }
    
    BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(MyLib)
    {
        using namespace boost::python;
        def("get", get);
    }
```

Python

```
from MyLib import get
get()
```

Comment: Are you in the same directory as your C++ library? Otherwise Python doesn't know where to find it.

Comment: Yes, .py file with .dll is in the same directory

Comment: `MyLib.dll` -- you're on Windows, it should be called `MyLib.pyd`.

Comment: if i change dll to pyd I get another error: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing MyLib: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: What version of CMake are you using?

Comment: 3.23.22060601-MSVC_2

Comment: Then use something like https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies to inspect which third party DLLs your module depends on, and make sure they're in the search path. You're probably linking with boost.python dynamically, so that is likely the culprit.

Comment: Yes, it seems you are right, I copied boost_python310 dll to my output path and it's working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that your binary module is named `MyLib.dll`. That is the first problem.[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8822335/3962537), [[2]](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/windows.html#is-a-pyd-file-the-same-as-a-dll)

On Windows, CPython expects binary modules to have extension `.pyd`.

Either rename the DLL manually, or (as you mention) use `PYTHON_ADD_MODULE` instead of `add_library` to achieve the same automatically.

Once you do this, another problem may appear:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing MyLib: The specified module could not be found.
```

When you're unsure, the best way to debug such errors on Windows is to use a tool like https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies to find which third party libraries are required, and possibly missing.

In this case, the likely culprit will be the boost.python DLL. Generally boost.python is linked dynamically, since that allows multiple binary modules that depend on it to work together. Make sure that DLL is in the library search path and things should work.