# django cannot import name 'Item'

Tags: python, django, import

After running a successful runserver,
To create a super user in django project, I updated the admin.py in my app directory as

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Item

admin.site.register(Item)
```

by running the following

$: python manage.py createsuperuser; 
I am getting the below error

[errorlog pastebin](http://pastebin.com/jhjYJHJW)

I am newbie to django and python, I read in other post about circular import but couldn't figure out error.

I have taken the tutorial from 
[Python and django youtube](https://youtu.be/ki85g_-wcec?t=26m11s).

Comment: Well, do you have a circular import? We can't tell without seeing your models file. Also please include all relevant details here in your question, don't link to offsite. It makes it easier for future users to find your question

Comment: Duplicate?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684408/django-cannot-import-name-x

Comment: Hi @Nicarus, as i have stated in the question itself i have read about circular import in other question from stackoverflow, as i am new to python here, can u help me figure out a solution.

Comment: Updating manage.py to do this sounds like a very bad idea.

Comment: this is my first project in django. Can u suggest other way. btw it was workin fine on the tutorial(given a link for that).

Comment: We need to see your models to diagnose this issue.

Comment: @IanAuld models.py :
from django.db import models

Comment: Do you mean to tell that your entire `models.py` is that one line?

Comment: Yes, I am running my first app

Comment: Okay, `Item` is not built in to Django. You have to actually define a model named `Item`. I'm guessing you missed a pretty substantial step in your tutorial.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118263/discussion-between-krishnakant-and-ianauld).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have identified the problem in this comment:

> models.py : from django.db import models

`Item` is not something that comes with Django. You will need to define a model named `Item` yourself. My guess is you ahve missed a pretty important step in your tutorial (or the tutorial is wrong/missing a step). However to get your app running in the meantime add to models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class Item(models.Model):
    pass
```

This should allow you to create a superuser. Be aware this model doesn't do anything. You will either have to find the missing step of your tutorial or figure out what it supposed to be doing.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's working for now. I will get to the missing part in the tutorial later.

Answer (score 1):

Do Not Update `manage.py`

There must be a file called `admin.py` in your app folder.
Whenever you create a new app, `admin.py` is automatically cerated in your app directory (`django-admin startapp your_app_name`  )

open admin.py:
move your code into it.

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Item  # Make sure you update this properly.

admin.site.register(Item)
```

Now Item should be listed in your admin panel.

PS: Make sure there are no circular import in your models.
The error you are getting is most likely resulting from a circular import.

Comment: Sorry a typo, I am updating the admin.py. Updated the question with the same.

Comment: @krishnakant well in this case, it would be best to see what is in your models.py file

Comment: 'from django.db import models

class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    
' models.py

Comment: @krishnakant are you importing your Item model in your app folders __ __init__ __.py ?

Comment: file __init__.py is empty. I am not importing anything

Comment: @krishnakant try turning your models.py into a module:

create a folder called models in the same dir where models.py is and  create a file called item.py and place your Item Model class in it.
Dont forget to remove models.py. 
Last create ____init____.py in models folder and do `from .item import Item` then in admin.py do `from models import Item`

Comment: do i have to remove init, admin, models original files ?

Comment: @krishnakant you only remove the models.py to avoid ambugiation between models.py and models folder(module). tou don't remove ____init____.py or any other.

Comment: @krishnakant like this one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336664/split-models-py-into-several-files

Comment: Thanks for helping. I have not  defined a model Item in models.py as mentioned by IanAuld.

Answer (score 0):

Is your `manage.py` and `models.py` in the same directory? `from .models import Item` means you are trying to import the `models` from the same package([relative import](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#guido-s-decision)), if not then you might need to do this(substitute `app` with your actual app name):

```
from app.models import Item
```

Also, it's really bad to register `admin` in `manage.py`. Django suggest doing it in the `admin.py` file in your app. Since `admin.py` is in the same package as `models.py`, it should just work. Check [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects) about this.

Comment: I just checked the link in your video, it doesn't even say that you should do it in `manage.py`, it clearly says it's in the file `admin.py`.

Comment: i am updating the admin.py, Updated the question with the correct file name. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Did you have a model called `Item` in `models.py`? Did you have `__init__.py` file in your app? Did you restart your server when you change your code?

Comment: yes i have 'class Item(models.Model):' in models.py along with __init__.py file in my app. I restarted the server.