# django and linking tables

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

I am trying to create a specialized membership application using django.  I am having some trouble planning out my app + table structure and data flow.  For example:  I have the basic django user model.  I am using a package called "allauth" and I have created a "Profile" model that holds basic person info.  I have tied all that together and it works for sign-up, account verification, logout and getting to a primitive "user page".  The next step is where I am getting a bit lost and getting an import error.

The person that creates a log-in must be 18 years old or more.  That person might be an adult member or the parent of one or more youth members or be both a parent and an adult member.  In any case the logged in person is thought of as being financially responsible for the member-account(s) associated with them.  There is also a case where more than one log-in person (like spouses) could share multiple "accounts" between them.  For example, either person in an adult couple could be financially responsible for paying the bills.

So, for a given log-in "profile" I need a `ManyToMany` relation to an "accounts" table.  An account can have `ManyToMany` relations to one or more member records and member "records" should live in the "profile" table but might not have login records in the "User" table.

Now we approach my problem.  With the `allauth` config and an `account_adaptor` method I have the django "User" model attached to the account profile, a la: (trimmed for brevity)

```
# PROFILE
    import uuid

    from auditlog.models import AuditlogHistoryField
    from auditlog.registry import auditlog
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.db import models

    from .account import Account


    class Profile(models.Model):
        id = models.UUIDField(
            max_length=32,
            default=uuid.uuid4,
            editable=False,
            primary_key=True,
            blank=False,
            null=False,
        )
        user = models.OneToOneField(
            User,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            unique=True,
            blank=True,
            null=True,
        )
        name_info = ...
        birthdate = models.DateField(
            blank=False,
            null=False
        )
        address_info = ...

# ACCOUNT
    import uuid

    from auditlog.models import AuditlogHistoryField
    from auditlog.registry import auditlog
    from django.db import models

    from .student import Student
    from Billing.models.payment import Payment


    class Account(models.Model):
        id = models.UUIDField(
            max_length=32,
            default=uuid.uuid4,
            editable=False,
            primary_key=True,
            blank=False,
            null=False,
        )
        students = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
        payments = models.ManyToManyField(Payment)


# STUDENT
    import uuid

    from auditlog.models import AuditlogHistoryField
    from auditlog.registry import auditlog
    from django.db import models

    from .profile import Profile


    class Student(models.Model):
        id = models.UUIDField(
            max_length=32,
            default=uuid.uuid4,
            editable=False,
            primary_key=True,
            blank=False,
            null=False,
        )
        profile = models.OneToOneField(
            Profile,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            unique=True,
            blank=False,
            null=False,
        )
```

When I do `makemigrations` I get the stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\me\myProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\me\myProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\me\myProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\me\myProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\me\myProject\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python3-6-5\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\me\myProject\myApp\Manager\models\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .group_list import *
  File "C:\me\myProject\myApp\Manager\models\group_list.py", line 5, in <module>
    from Members.models.profile import Profile
  File "C:\me\myProject\myApp\Members\models\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .profile import *
  File "C:\me\myProject\myApp\Members\models\profile.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .account import Account
  File "C:\me\myProject\myApp\Members\models\account.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .student import Student
  File "C:\me\myProject\myApp\Members\models\student.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .profile import Profile
ImportError: cannot import name 'Profile'
```

My thought is that this is creating some circular linking that django doesn't  but I don't understand this well enought to work around it.

Thoughts: the Student table could be its own table but that feels wastful as the Profile table already has the necessary columns

**Edit**

I think this is a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684408/django-cannot-import-name-x)

Comment: You want to use the entire package structure, not just `.profile` but starting from your project root - if you have app named `users` then it should be `from users.models import Profile` - considering `users` is in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: If I change `from .profile import Profile` to `from Members.models.profile import Profile`; make similar changes in the other models and make sure that `Members` and `Billing` are in `INSTALLED_APPS` I get the same error.

Comment: You're still having several places where the location is not related to project root - also the default Django location for models is `models.py` - not models *package* directory - so the models have to be declared in `models.py`

Comment: I hope that I am not confusing issues here... each of the "applications" of Members and Billing have model "folders". So I don't have `models.py` files; I have `Members/models/profile.py` and `Members/models/student.py`, etc.  If I have misunderstood your intent, I am sorry.

Comment: If using directory, than it has to have `__init__.py` in it - like here https://williamsbdev.com/posts/django-models-directory/

Comment: Yes, I am using that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django cannot import name x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684408/django-cannot-import-name-x)