# Django - Conflict between my django models.py files

Tags: django, django-models

I don't see any conflicts with the following. What am I doing wrong? I get the following error `ImportError: cannot import name 'Business' from 'business.models'` I assume maybe I am doing some type of circular loop, but I do not see it.:

```
#links/models.py
from django.db import models

class LinkType(models.Model):
    link_type = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.link_type

from business.models import Business

class Link(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    link_type = models.ForeignKey(LinkType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['business', 'link_type']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

#business/models.py
from django.db import models
from links.models import LinkType

class Business(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    main_link_type = models.ForeignKey(LinkType, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django related field accepts the **`to`** parameter as ***string*** too. The value should be in **`app_name.ModelName`** format.

```
class Link(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey('business.Business', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   # rest of your code

# business/models.py

class Business(models.Model):
    main_link_type = models.ForeignKey('links.LinkType', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   # rest of your code
```

Comment: Can you add to your answer what imports I need to make. For example above the `Link` model do I need to do `from business.models import Business`?

Comment: Remove both the imports in the Business and LinkType models. Then update the above two lines. Removing just one import might also work. Maybe check that too.

Comment: In my answer the `to` is string and it doesn't involve or rely on any kind imports. @Padoga . Also, follow `twothreezarsix`'s comment.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a circular import. In the business model, you are importing the links model and in the links model you are importing the business model.

Here are links to similar questions which might help:

[ImportError: Cannot import name X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252543/importerror-cannot-import-name-x)

[Django cannot import name x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684408/django-cannot-import-name-x)